# command line arguments in hive ( .hql) files from a bash script

Tags: bash, hql, command-line-arguments

I am having a main bash script running several other bash scripts and hql files.  The hql files have hive queries.  The hive queries have a where clause and it is on the date field. I am trying to automate a process and I need the where clause to change based on todays date ( which is obtained from the main bash script).

For example the .hql file looks like this:
This is `selectrows.hql`

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tv.events_tmp;
CREATE TABLE tv.events_tmp
(   origintime STRING,
 deviceid STRING,
 clienttype STRING,
 loaddate STRING)
 ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\u0001'
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
 STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION 'hdfs://nameservice1/data/full/events_tmp';

INSERT INTO TABLE tv.events_tmp SELECT origintime, deviceid, clienttype, loaddate FROM tv.events_tmp WHERE origintime >= '2015-11-02 00:00:00' AND origintime < '2015-11-03 00:00:00';
```

Since today is 2015-11-11, i want to be able to pass the `date - 9 days` and `date-8 days` to the .hql script from the bash script.  Is there a way to pass these two variable from the bash script to the .hql file.

So the main bash script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# today's date
prodate=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
echo $prodate
dateneeded=`date -d "$prodate - 8 days" +%Y-%m-%d`
echo $dateneeded

# CREATE temp table
beeline -u 'jdbc:hive2://datanode:10000/;principal=hive/datanode@HADOOP.INT.BELL.CA' -d org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver -f /home/automation/tv/selectrows.hql
echo "created table"
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the hql file used as an argument/input to some other command? Does that command/etc. support variables? If not you could always use placeholders `@DATE1@`, etc. in the `.hql` file and then replace those at runtime (with `sed`, etc.).

Comment: Hi Etan, please see, i've updated some info

Comment: That's nice but doesn't answer my questions. It does indicate that the placeholder solution would work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `beeline -e` option to execute queries using strings. Then pass the date parameters to the strings.

```
#!/bin/bash
# today's date
prodate=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
echo $prodate
dateneeded8=`date -d "$prodate - 8 days" +%Y-%m-%d`
dateneeded9=`date -d "$prodate - 9 days" +%Y-%m-%d`
echo $dateneeded8
echo $dateneeded9

hql="
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tv.events_tmp;
CREATE TABLE tv.events_tmp
(   origintime STRING,
 deviceid STRING,
 clienttype STRING,
 loaddate STRING)
 ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\u0001'
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
 STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION 'hdfs://nameservice1/data/full/events_tmp';

INSERT INTO TABLE tv.events_tmp SELECT origintime, deviceid, clienttype, loaddate FROM tv.events_tmp WHERE origintime >= '"

echo "$hql""$dateneeded9""' AND origintime < '""$dateneeded8""';"

# CREATE temp table
beeline -u 'jdbc:hive2://datanode:10000/;principal=hive/datanode@HADOOP.INT.BELL.CA' -d org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver -e "$hql""$dateneeded9""' AND origintime < '""$dateneeded8""';"
echo "created table"
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way to pass an argument

**create hive .hql file with defined variables**

```
vi multi_var_file.hql 
SELECT * FROM TEST_DB.TEST_TB WHERE TEST1='${var_1}' AND TEST2='${var_2}';
```

**Pass the same variables into the Hive script to run**

```
hive -hivevar var_1='TEST1' -hivevar var_2='TEST2' -f multi_var_file.hql
```